# container not building with mentioned dockerfile - multiple containers

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am working with a case where there is a main kernel application that uses **mysql** and **influxdb** as the databases and **grafana** for showing the data pictorially. I am creating separate containers for each using `docker-compose` and individual `Dockerfile`s.

The folder structure is as such :

dockercompose

- docker-compose.yml
- kernel

  - Dockerfilekernel
  - app.war
- sqldb

  - Dockerfilesqldb
  - dump.sql
  - startup.sh
- grafana

  - Dockerfilegrafana
  - grafana.env
  - run.sh
- tsdbdb

  - Dockerfiletsdb
  - influxdb.env
  - init-influxdb.sh
  - entrypoint.sh

---

The container for kernel builds but on checking the logs, it is displaying the logs of influxdb, the same that displays on checking the logs for tsdbdb container.

Code for `docker-compose` :

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysqldb:
        build: 
            context: ./sqldb
            dockerfile: Dockerfilesqldb
        container_name: sql
        command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
        volumes:
        - ./sqldb:/app/sql
        restart: always
        expose:
        - "3306"
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
        environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secretpassword
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbtest
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    tsdbdb:
        build: 
            context: ./tsdbdb
            dockerfile: Dockerfiletsdb
        container_name: influx
        restart: always
        expose:
        - "8083"
        - "8086"
        ports:
        - "8083:8083"
        - "8086:8086"
        volumes:
        - ./tsdb:/app/tsdb
        env_file:
        - './tsdbdb/influxdb.env'
    grafana:
        build: 
            context: ./grafana
            dockerfile: Dockerfilegrafana
        container_name: grafana
        env_file:
        - './grafana/grafana.env'
        expose:
        - "3000"
        ports:
        - "3003:3000"
        links:
        - tsdbdb
    web:
        build: 
            context: ./kernel
            dockerfile: Dockerfilekernel
        container_name: kernel
        restart: always
        expose:
        - "8080"
        ports:
        - "8082:8080"
        depends_on:
        - mysqldb
        links:
        - tsdbdb
        - mysqldb
        volumes:
        - ./kernel:/app/kernel
```

**Dockerfile** of kernel :

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre-alpine

ENV JHIPSTER_SLEEP 0

WORKDIR /app/kernel

# add directly the war
ADD *.war /app/kernel/app.war

RUN sh -c 'touch /app/kernel/app.war'
VOLUME /tmp

EXPOSE 8080

CMD echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} && \
    java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/kernel/app.war
```

**Dockerfile** for influxdb, *just in case* :

```
FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-curl

WORKDIR /app/tsdb

RUN set -ex && \
    for key in \
        05CE15085FC09D18E99EFB22684A14CF2582E0C5 ; \
    do \
        gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
        gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
        gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done

ENV INFLUXDB_VERSION 1.2.4
ENV INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD secretpassword
ENV INFLUXDB_DB master_db

RUN ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" && \
    case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in \
      amd64) ARCH='amd64';; \
      arm64) ARCH='arm64';; \
      armhf) ARCH='armhf';; \
      armel) ARCH='armel';; \
      *)     echo "Unsupported architecture: ${dpkgArch}"; exit 1;; \
    esac && \
    wget -q https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb.asc && \
    wget -q https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb && \
    gpg --batch --verify influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb.asc influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb && \
    dpkg -i influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb && \
    rm -f influxdb_${INFLUXDB_VERSION}_${ARCH}.deb*
COPY influxdb.conf /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

EXPOSE 8086

VOLUME /var/lib/influxdb

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY init-influxdb.sh /init-influxdb.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["influxd"]
```

---

It might be possible that this is happening due to a silly mistake but I am not able to find where exactly is the problem.

Comment: If you haven't made mistakes in your structure, the `Dockerfilesqldb` should be named `Dockerfilesql` according to your docker-compose file.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing error, edited the question.

Comment: I side stepped this by placing all the dockerfiles in the directory containing the docker-compose.yml. Dockerfile-dev, Dockerfile-php, etc. So that is an approach you could take, but it would be nice to have a directory p/service. I haven't been brave enough to try symlinks.

Comment: so basically what I should try to do is keep all the Dockerfiles in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem by doing the following -

Changed the service name from **web** to **kernel** and in `docker-compose.yml` I added the **command** line for kernel service:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysqldb:
        build: 
            context: ./sqldb
            dockerfile: Dockerfilesqldb
        container_name: sql
        command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
        # volumes:
        # - ./sqldb:/app/sql
        restart: always
        # expose:
        # - "3306"
        ports:
        - "3306:3306"
        environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secretpassword
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbtest
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    tsdbdb:
        build: 
            context: ./tsdbdb
            dockerfile: Dockerfiletsdb
        container_name: influx
        restart: always
        # expose:
        # - "8083"
        # - "8086"
        ports:
        - "8083:8083"
        - "8086:8086"
        # volumes:
        # - ./tsdb:/app/tsdb
        env_file:
        - './tsdbdb/influxdb.env'
    grafana:
        build: 
            context: ./grafana
            dockerfile: Dockerfilegrafana
        container_name: grafana
        env_file:
        - './grafana/grafana.env'
        expose:
        - "3000"
        ports:
        - "3003:3000"
        links:
        - tsdbdb
    kernel:
        build: 
            context: ./kernel
            dockerfile: Dockerfilekernel
        container_name: kernel
        command: java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/kernel/app.war
        restart: always
        # expose:
        # - "8080"
        ports:
        - "8082:8080"
        links:
        - tsdbdb
        - mysqldb
        # volumes:
        # - ./kernel:/app/kernel
```

*Although I am not sure why only adding **command** solved the problem.*